# Does C's void* serve any purpose other than making code more idiomatic?

Tags: c, void-pointers

Does C's `void*` lend some benefit in the form of compiler optimization etc, or is it just an idiomatic equivalent for `char*`? I.e. if every `void*` in the C standard library was replaced by `char*`, would anything be damaged aside from code legibility?

Comment: void* is used for an unknown type,and can be used if you are getting input or sorting through a random list of different types.

Comment: You say you want your language to be "devoid of any type aliasing", but you're planning to cast arbitrary pointers to `uint8*`?

Comment: @Camden Yes I know what it's generally used for. I'm asking if it allows for better compiler optimization, etc, or really any purpose other that making code more clear.

Comment: `void *` is useful for functions like `memcpy` and `malloc` where the function is dealing with memory without any concern for what's stored in that memory.

Comment: void* in C and C++ is not limited to byte buffers it is used to pass any kind of buffer, object, struct.

Comment: @user2357112 Casting arbitrary pointers? There will be no arbitrary pointers if `void*` does not have any optimization purpose or the like. That is why I asked the question. If `void*` doesn't, `[u]int8*`s will **be** the arbitrary pointers in my language.

Comment: What would the type signature for `malloc` would look like in your language? (does your language support generics/templates?)

Comment: void* is basically the c++ version of the objective-c _id*_

Comment: Yes my language supports templating. I'm asking if there's really any reason `[u]int8*` shouldn't be used everywhere `void*` is used in C.

Comment: @SamClaus: You're planning to take pointers to types that aren't `uint8` and cast them to `uint8*`.

Comment: Declaring a pointer as uint8* is also declaring how arithmetic should work on that pointer. Declaring it as void* signals that you aren't telling the compiler how to do arithmetic on it.

Comment: also you cannot assign something to void* such as this: `void* v = 5;int i = v //error`

Comment: Here's the thing though. GCC supports pointer arithmetic on `void*`, and it works just like arithmetic on a `char*` anyways.

Comment: That is non-standard. But from above comments, how would you write a `malloc` for a type defined by you?

Comment: @Camden I am perfectly aware of how `void*` works. I asked if `void*` does anything special for the compiler, or if its only purpose is saying "I don't care about type".

Comment: @WeatherVane I would define it the same as `malloc` is now, except with `uint8*` instead of `void*`. Please read the question.

Comment: I am asking how you would write a malloc, for a non-standard type, such as a `struct`. I can see how you would supply a variety of `malloc` for every standard type.

Comment: `void*` is a *generic* pointer type introduced later into the C language. In fact K&R C *did* use `char*` for this purpose. The main disadvantage was that you cannot declare a function that really takes a pointer to characters and not anything else because it was already used for any generic function. E.g. `strcmp` could take raw storage.

Comment: void* is just a "who cares what it is".

Comment: @Marcel Thank you. That was the answer I needed, not 20 people telling the same thing that I literally explained myself in the question.

Comment: I did read the question, it says "devoid of any type aliasing".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes as in you will not see anything like `typedef MyCustomIntType = short`. I mean I want only the necessary primitive types. If `void*` doesn't serve a purpose other than being an intuitive alias for `char*` in some situations, i don't want it in my language, because my language has named parameters [in function calls] to make such code clear to read anyways.

Comment: No, but you might see `typedef struct { ... } mystruct;` So, do you understand why I asked how you will supply a library `malloc` equivalent for that, without type aliasing?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm saying that my language will not have `typedef`, period. There will be no such thing as struct tags, only solid struct types that you define and use like any other type. If some code needs to access raw memory and doesn't care about type, it can just use a `[u]int8*` to access those bytes. In my language, `malloc` would simply return a `uint8*`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe we're not on the same page. I am talking about C's `malloc` function where you tell it allocate `n` bytes and it returns a raw pointer to that memory.

Comment: Then perhaps you should delete the phrase "devoid of any type aliasing" from the question. Whether or not a `struct` is a formal `typedef` you still get the wrong type of pointer from `malloc` - ah you did so as I typed.

Comment: `uint8_t` is not equivalent to `char`, these type are **different**, `char` is not guaranty to have 8 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original K&R C there was no `void *` type, `char *` was used as the generic pointer.

`void *` serves two main purposes:

1. It makes it clear when a pointer is being used as a generic pointer. Previously, you couldn't tell whether `char *` was being used as a pointer to an actual character buffer or as a generic pointer.
2. It allows the compiler to catch errors where you try to dereference or perform arithmetic on a generic pointer, rather than casting it to the appropriate type first. These operations aren't permitted on `void *` values. Unfortunately, some compilers (e.g. `gcc`) allow arithmetic on `void *` pointers by default, so it's not as safe as it could be.

Comment: Note that GCC has an extension (that's enabled by default) that permits arithmetic on `void *`, behaving as if it were `char *`.  This is not wholly unreasonable given the standard's requirement ([C11 §6.2.5 ¶28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html/#6.2.5p28)): _A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type._ But it does subvert the protection you mention.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hence "allow" rather than "forces".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Does it allow dereferencing them? That will still catch it if you try to use the result without casting.

Comment: I don't think you can dereference a `void *` even in GCC.  At one level, the deviation in GCC is mostly reasonable — it saves some casting to `char *` before calculating offsets — but it does go against the standard and catches novices unawares.  (The GCC folks would probably say that they aren't catering to novices nor are they concerned about portability to other compilers.  And `-pedantic` catches the abuse.  But it does require `-pedantic`; otherwise, it is allowed uncommented upon.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My language is supposed to be very explicit anyways, so I want to force people to write casts, so an implicit cast to something like `void*` would be undesirable IMHO anyways.

Comment: @SamClaus You don't need to allow implicit casts. C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, interesting. Still, with my language I don't want implicit casts to even be an option (and I have named parameters in function calls), so it should almost always be pretty clear when someone is passing a pointer for raw memory access.

Comment: But you said you're using `uint8*` as your generic pointer. How will that be distinguished from pointers to actual integers?

Comment: I think you left out the arguably more important purpose: allowing functions that take or return a pointer to data where the type doesn't matter without the awfulness and human-semantic wrongness of a cast to `char *` or some other arbitrary type. In particular, `malloc` and `free` need `void *` not to be awful. See also: their use in C++ which lacks a working `void *`.

Comment: @R.. C programmers got along for years using `char *` for those purposes, it wasn't "awful".

Answer (score 3):

C got along just fine for years with `char *` as the generic pointer type before `void *` was introduced later. So it clearly isn't strictly necessary. But programming languages are communication--not just telling a compiler what to do, but telling other human beings reading the program what is intended. Anything that makes a language more expressive is a good thing.

Comment: Thank you. That was why I stated that my language has named parameters [for function calls]. Thus, instead of feeding a function an unnamed `char*` that might confuse anyone reading the code, the parameter might be named `rawptr`, so the code calling the function is still clear without need for `void*`.

Comment: @SamClaus: You claim that named function parameters obviates the need for a void* type, yet C also has named function parameters, and uses a void* type (for good reason).

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Well, firstly I edited my question to dumb it down and remove the context of my language design in order to make what I'm trying to figure out as clear as possible, but since you bring it up: I meant when you **call** the function you name the parameters, and the parameter name that takes a raw pointer should be named appropriately so anywhere the function is used it is obvious what the pointer will be used for. And I believe a call to a function `myFunc(void* ptr)` like `myFunc(myStructPtr)` will implicitly cast to a `void*`, meaning `void*` doesn't even help legibility.

Comment: @SamClaus: The whole point of using void* is to resolve ambiguity. If you say that it's not necessary because developers can be relied upon to use proper and meaningful argument names, I'm afraid you're being overly optimistic.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield You're correct--I know I am guilty of plenty of bad argument names--but I have to weigh the pros and cons, and since `void*` is only useful idiomatically in situations where the dev is already expected to know what they are doing in C (and GCC allows arithmetic on it like a `char*`), I'd rather leave it out and have fewer primitives.

Comment: @SamClaus: Alright, leaving aside the question of using argument names to provide context, how do you propose to deal with generic functions like callbacks without an implicit generic pointer type?

Answer (score 1):

> Does C's void* serve any purpose other than making code more idiomatic?
>
> if every `void*` in the C standard library was replaced by `char*`, would anything be damaged aside from code legibility?

C11 introduced `_Genric`.  Because of that, `_Generic(some_C_standard_library_function()) ...` code can compile quite differently depending on if the return type was a `void *`, `char *`, `int *`, etc.